# Do mathematicians implicitly assume all random variable map to the real line?

Tags: probability, random-variables, convention

I just want to confirm a convention in probability that whenever we talk about a random variable, we assume that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.

That is, whenever $A$ is a random variable, $\text{codomain}(A) = \mathbb{R}$

Is this correct?

I just feel like this is a very unfortunate omission in most elementary probability textbooks.  The textbook authors then go on $5$ more chapters talking about these scalar-valued random variables.

Because in real-life, almost all random experiments include a large set of variables, hence almost all real-life random experiments involve "vectorized random variable" or "stacked random variable". At least this is the case when you grab any dataset from a repository.

Hence to beginners this may seem that the whole idea of random variable is useless or not practical. I mean just look at the most elementary data from Kaggle, you would at least have 2 entries (height,weight), (age, degree). Hence almost all random variable on Kaggle are vectorized random variables.

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition).

Comment: But look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_element A random variable is the simplest type of random element. It is a map $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb {R}$  is a measurable function from the set of possible outcomes $\Omega  \to \mathbb {R}$ .

Comment: Have you read the first sentences of the paragraphs "Standard case" and "Extensions" in the article Kenny Lau linked to? -- I admit I have seen texts with the explicit convention that random variables are real-valued, which is obviously the basic interesting case for statistics. Next level would be $\mathbb R^d$. I think it is a convention which might differ between sources and applications.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I did. But then it said the general case is a random element. So that means to me that random variable map to $\mathbb{R}$ and random element map to more arbitrary sets. Since a random element is not necessarily a random variable, therefore my question about the convention remains.

Comment: It's certainly my experience that "random variable" usually means real-valued unless otherwise specified, either explicitly or from context.

Comment: I think the Russian school kept that distinction (Kolmogorov's original definition was random variables are real-valued) while the rest of the world happily use the term "random variable" for both real-valued and general $E$-valued.